# How to calculate limit of a recursive without starting point?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

I want to find limit of the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n(2-ax_n)$ but I don't have the start point. Is it possible to find it's limit when $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Why not leave $x_0$ or $x_1$ (or whatever other starting term you like) as a variable and find the limit in terms of that variable?  What is preventing you doing so?

Comment: @EricTowers I want to know can I reach a number without any variable?

Comment: Have you shown that the limit *actually* depends on the starting value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(we exclude the case $a=0$)

I assume you are familiar with fixed-point iterations $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ with convergence to a limit point $L$ such that $L=f(L)$ with sufficient condition $|f'(L)|<1$ and $f(I) \subset I$ for a certain subset $I$ containing $L$. [Here, as we will see, $f'(L)=0$ and interval $I$ is $[0,a]$].

Let $P_a$ be the curve (parabola) with equation $f_a(x)=x(2-ax)$. It intersects $x$ axis in $x=0$ and $x=\frac{2}{a}$ and its vertex is $(\tfrac{1}{a},\tfrac{1}{a})$.

We have a fixed-point equation $f_a(x)=x$.

Take a look at the following figure with different cases ranging from $a=-2$ to $a=2$ .

[image]

The intersections of parabola $P_a$ with oblique line $y=x$ are very special:

- the origin, and
- the vertex (minimum or maximum) of $P_a$.

Therefore, as the values of the derivative in such a point is $0$, this guarantees that there is convergence.

If $a>0$, it remains to show that

- Whatever the **positive** initial value $x_0$, sequence $x_n$ is convergent indeed towards $L=\tfrac{1}{a}$ with interval $I=[0,a]$.
- Whatever the **negative** initial value $x_0$, szquence $x_n$ is divergent.

If $a<0$, you have to show the symmetrical phenomenon:

- if $x_0<0$ the convergence is towards vertex $(\tfrac{1}{a},\tfrac{1}{a})$.
- if $x_0>0$ there is divergence.

"Verification" using the following Matlab program that generates the figure:

> ```
> hold on;axis equal;x=-2:0.01:2;
> p=2;axis(p*[-1,1,-1,1]);
> plot(x,x,'k');
> for a=-2:1/8:2
>    plot(1/a,1/a,'or');
>    plot(x,x.*(2-a*x));
>    y=sign(a)*rand;%random initial value
>    for k=1:100
>       y=y*(2-a*y);
>    end;% a hundred steps
>    plot(y,y,'or');% "almost" the limit
> end;
> ```

Comment: The fixed point iteration may converge even if $f$ is not contractive and invariant on $I$, so it is not correct to point it as a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: @PierreCarre You are right, it is a sufficient condition.